# Issue with removing a library from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I deleted a version of a library, and now I'm getting the error "Library with identifier XXXXX is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)". I am also unable to remove the reference to the library. My code now won't run due to the aforementioned error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Well, did you remove all references to the script library from your code? This includes dependencies such as published webapps.

Comment: Yup, removed them all

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to accomplish this.
1. I need to be owner of the project that has the reference I'm trying to remove
2. Backup the code
3. In Script editor, open the project that has the reference I'm trying to remove
4. Select File - Delete Project
5. Close Script Editor
6. Create a new project, and import the previous code
7. Select Resources - Library to re-add the reference to the library